# Nginx AIO & FastCGI Streaming

Tags: nginx, php

Will [nginx aio](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html?&_ga=1.159072690.948180374.1456137422#aio) makes any difference when it is being used with FastCGI (PHP) ?

I'm currently using PHP to read Files and with the help of nginx data reaches the client.

I have more than 5.000 Concurrent users reading endless files(live streaming) with this way.
Will nginx aio change something on it? It can improve the perfomance? Or it doesn't matter because PHP is handling this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Is the live streaming static files? if so , pls try:
`http {
    sendfile           on;`
and make a location to the file path.